# HTTP links still in Google's SERPs after moving to HTTPS

Tags: google, https, search-results

I've moved my WordPress site from **HTTP** to **HTTPS** almost a month ago. Here are the steps that I've taken:

- Replace all the internal links over the site like navigation etc. (HTTP links still there in content)
- Changed the protocol in Google Analytics.
- Add new property in Web Master Tools with the HTTPS protocol.
- Force HTTPS everywhere via `.htaccess` file
- Change the site address in WordPress admin panel

After all these, Google still keeps HTTP links in SERPs and whenever I Google `https://example.com` it goes:

> Did you mean `http://example.com`

Moreover, when I Google `site:example.com inurl:http` it returns like 1450 results, and for `site:example.com inurl:http://example.com` it returns 130 results.

In my opinion, something makes my site stuck in HTTP and does not let it be HTTPS.

Is there anyone here with any suggestions?

Comment: "http links still there in content" - So, you've _not_ replaced all the internal links?

Comment: nope because they are all 301 redirected. and there's maximum 2 links in each articles, no big deal?

Comment: "because they are all 301 redirected" is not a reason to not change these links to HTTPS. A `site:` search will return URLs that are the source of a redirect (which would not get returned in a normal search) - this is "normal" behaviour. Ordinarily you would only get a "Did you mean" prompt when there is a difference in the domain itself, not just the protocol? I'm not sure what you are trying to show with your example... for the "130 results", did you mean to write something including the HTTPS protocol eg. `site:example.com inurl:https`?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like you have done anything wrong.   Google sometimes takes weeks or months to get new URLs indexed perfectly after a mass URL change.  In the meantime, any user that gets directed to HTTP will get properly redirected to HTTPS.  The "did you mean" will eventually disappear but it may take a while.

The only thing that you should make double sure is that your redirects are really the 301 permanent variety.   If you are using 302 temporary redirects, Google will take much longer to move things over.  Use a command line like `curl --head http://example.com/` and make sure it is a 301 or use a checker site like [this one](http://www.redirect-checker.org/).

As [user82217](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1243/user82217) says in the comments, the `site:` search results are not very reliable.   Google often shows redirect results and duplicate content in a `site:` search that it will never show otherwise.